# Not able to assign ::1/128 to a different interface other than lo

Tags: networking, ipv6, localhost

When lo interface is created, it has 2 localhost addresses, 127.0.0.1/8 for IPV4 and ::1/128 for IPV6.
I need to have the same localhost addresses on a different interface in a different VRF (management VRF). I'm able to assign 127.0.0.1/8 to the new interface(mgmt interface) without problem, but I'm not able to assign ::1/128 to it.

I tried 2 ways, for example,

1. ```
   ip -6 addr add 127.0.0.1/8 dev mgmt
   ```
2. in `/etc/network/interfaces`,

   ```
   auto mgmt
   iface mgmt
   address 127.0.0.1/8
   address ::1/128
   vrf-table auto
   ```

They all failed with the same error:

```
RTNETLINK answers: Cannot assign requested address
```

The mgmt interface is created with only ipv4 localhost address 127.0.0.1/8, but not the IPV6 one.
Tried with other interfaces, but seems ::1/128 can be only added on the lo interface.

```
mgmt: flags=1217<UP,RUNNING,NOARP,MASTER>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        ether 66:30:aa:7d:d7:b7  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 574  bytes 83958 (81.9 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1  bytes 146 (146.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Does anyone know why it only works for IPV4 localhost and not IPV6 localhost? What else can I do to make ::1/128 to be added to a differernt interface, in a non-default instance?